# How to 301 redirect one page of a site to another page in a sub-directory using .htacess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, directory

I am migrating a site, but the new site is an "addon" domain in cPanel which is filed as a **sub-directory** of the main site.

So how do I 301 redirect one page of the old site to the same page on the new site considering the above?

I've tried

```
Redirect 301 /page1.php http://www.newsite.com/page1.php
```

But that makes page1.php on the new site go into an infinite loop.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to your .htaccess file in the root of your old domain

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# if request is on the old domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.olddomain\.com$
#for page1.php, then redirect it to new domain
RewriteRule ^page1.php$ http://www.newdomain.com/page1.php [L,R=301]

# or use below to redirect any php page to the new domain
RewriteRule ^(.+).php$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1.php [L,R=301]
```

EDIT:
If you want to redirect **everything** on the old site to the new site then use the code below.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# if request is on the old domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.olddomain\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

If you want to just redirect the home page of old to new replace RewriteRule above with

```
#just redirect the home page
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.newdomain.com/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks!  The second solution is against Google's best practices when migrating, so I'm going to go with the first solution, which worked.  But how do I redirect just the main domain so that www.oldsite.com redirects to www.newsite.com ?  I tried doing the redirect with "index.php", but that only works if you actually add /index.php to the domain of the old site.  Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you need to use `od rewrite`? Can't this be done via `redirect 301`? (I don't know the answer, I am just curious as to why...) @UlrichPalha